# Frequently getting contacted by my boss after I clocked off

Tags: management, remote-work, after-hours

I may be biased because I'm talking about myself, but I get the feeling that I get contacted more often than not, after I punched out. For example, today I asked my boss about some work and he never answered. Some minutes after I logged out from my laptop (I'm working remotely) I hear the internal messaging app on my phone.

Could there be a reason he feels entitled to do that?

Comment: I'm assuming what you're really asking is what to do about it and not literally asking for an answer for why he does it.

Comment: "Could there be a reason he feels entitled to do that?"  If you respond to him after you punch out, that could be the reason.

Comment: Some countries have laws about this and the employer / manager cannot contact you outside work time - unless your are on a special contract.

Answer (score 5):

First get clarity on what are the official hours from your manager. If he is contacting outside of official hours unless it is urgent do not reply. If this happens frequently take it up with your manager and HR if required and again get it clarified what is expected from you in such situations.

If they tell you they expect reply from you within X minutes/hours outside of working hours then we are renegotiating roles, responsibilities and compensation.

I am also working remotely and since I am in India and clients are in US and other time zones, I get messages at unusual times but I only reply in my official working hours unless there is something very urgent.

Also if not already try putting hours worked on time sheet and make sure you include outside working hours as over time and make sure you are getting compensated for the same.

Comment: hahaha. This works if only the company is matured. In india its rare to find some